# Understanding TFLite Quantization

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-lite

I want to understand how TFLite rescales the layer output from 32bit to 8bit using only integer operations. For this, I built the following minimal example consisting of a dense-layer, without bias. Besides, I wrote the function `int_based_rescale()` to rescale the layer output only using integer operations. Unfortunately, I get off-by-one errors, as can be seen below. Probably I am rounding wrong at one point? Thank you!

```py
import math
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow_model_optimization as tfmot

# Train small model on MNIST dataset
model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
        keras.layers.Dense(10, use_bias=False),
    ]
)

data = keras.datasets.mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = data.load_data()

train_images = train_images / 255.0
test_images = test_images / 255.0

model.compile(
    optimizer="adam",
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)

model.fit(
    train_images,
    train_labels,
    epochs=1,
    validation_split=0.1,
)

# Make model quantization aware
quantize_model = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_model
q_aware_model = quantize_model(model)
q_aware_model.compile(
    optimizer="adam",
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)

# Optimize model on data subset
train_images_subset = train_images[0:1000]
train_labels_subset = train_labels[0:1000]

q_aware_model.fit(
    train_images_subset,
    train_labels_subset,
    batch_size=500,
    epochs=1,
    validation_split=0.1,
)

# Evaluate quantization aware model
_, baseline_model_accuracy = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels, verbose=0)

_, q_aware_model_accuracy = q_aware_model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels, verbose=0)

print("Baseline accuracy:", baseline_model_accuracy)
print("Quantized accuracy:", q_aware_model_accuracy)

# Baseline accuracy: 0.9128999710083008
# Quantized accuracy: 0.9154000282287598

####

# Convert to TFLite model
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(q_aware_model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8
quantized_tflite_model = converter.convert()

def quantize(x, scale, zero_point, dtype=tf.uint8):
    y = tf.divide(x, scale)
    y = tf.round(y)
    y = tf.add(y, zero_point)
    y = tf.saturate_cast(y, dtype).numpy()
    return y

def set_input_tensor(interpreter, input):
    input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()[0]
    tensor_index = input_details["index"]
    input_tensor = interpreter.tensor(tensor_index)()[0]
    scale, zero_point = input_details["quantization"]
    input_tensor[:, :] = quantize(input, scale, zero_point)

def evaluate_model(interpreter):
    output_index = interpreter.get_output_details()[0]["index"]

    correct = 0

    # Run predictions on every image in the "test" dataset.
    for i, test_image in enumerate(test_images):
        set_input_tensor(interpreter, test_image)
        
        # Run inference.
        interpreter.invoke()
        prediction = interpreter.get_tensor(output_index)
        prediction_class = np.argmax(prediction)
        if prediction_class == test_labels[i]:
            correct += 1

    accuracy = correct / float(len(test_images))
    return accuracy

interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_content=quantized_tflite_model)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
test_accuracy = evaluate_model(interpreter)

print('Quantized TFLite test_accuracy:', test_accuracy)

# Quantized TFLite test_accuracy: 0.9154

####

# Single inferene on quantized TFLite model
def inference_model(interpreter, test_image):
    set_input_tensor(interpreter, test_image)
    interpreter.invoke()

    input_index = interpreter.get_input_details()[0]["index"]
    output_index = interpreter.get_output_details()[0]["index"]
    prediction = interpreter.get_tensor(output_index)
    input_tensor = interpreter.get_tensor(input_index)

    return prediction, input_tensor

tf_lite_pred, tf_lite_q_input = inference_model(interpreter, test_images[0])
print('Qunatized TFLite prediction: ', tf_lite_pred)

# Qunatized TFLite prediction:  [[ 73   0 100 153  47  71   0 255  90 152]]

####

# Try do reproduce the qunatized TFLite prediction with plain code
def get_q_parameter(index):
    details = interpreter.get_tensor_details()
    for detail in details:
        if detail['index'] == index:
            scales = detail["quantization_parameters"]["scales"]
            zero_points = detail["quantization_parameters"]["zero_points"]
            return scales, zero_points
        
# Get weights from model and quantize them
weights = q_aware_model.get_weights()[4]
w_scale, w_zero_point = get_q_parameter(4)
weights_q = quantize(weights, w_scale, w_zero_point, np.int8)
weights_q = interpreter.get_tensor(4).T

# Quantize input
input = np.array([test_images[0]], dtype=np.float32)
in_scale, in_zero_point = interpreter.get_input_details()[0]['quantization']
input_q = quantize(input, in_scale, in_zero_point)

# Compute dense output
dense_output = np.matmul(weights_q.T, input_q.flatten(), dtype=np.int32)
print('Dense output: ', dense_output)

# Scale output down - float-based
out_scale, out_zero_point = interpreter.get_output_details()[0]['quantization']
M = (w_scale * in_scale) / out_scale
out_rescaled = quantize(dense_output, 1/M, out_zero_point)
print('Output rescaled: ', out_rescaled)

# Scale output down - int-based
def int_based_rescale(x, M, zero_point):
    shifts = math.floor(abs(math.log(M, 2)))
    M0 = M / pow(2, -shifts)
    M0 = M0 * pow(2, 31)
    M0 = M0.astype(np.int64)
    x_int64 = x.astype(np.int64)
    x_int64 = x_int64 * M0
    x_int64 = x_int64 >> 31
    x_int32 = x_int64.astype(np.int32)

    x_int32 = x_int32 >> shifts
    x_int32 = x_int32 + zero_point
    y = tf.saturate_cast(x_int32, np.uint8).numpy()
    return y

out_rescaled_int = int_based_rescale(dense_output, M, out_zero_point)
print('Output rescaled int: ', out_rescaled_int)

# Dense output:  [-169119 -571574  -85471   77999 -248345 -174496 -491065  459797 -118140
   73661]
# Output rescaled:  [ 73   0 100 153  47  71   0 255  90 152]
# Output rescaled int:  [ 72   0 100 153  47  71   0 255  89 151]
```